# Azure sql editions in ARM template are not giving exact errors to fix them

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-sql-database, continuous-deployment, azure-resource-manager

When deploying with Arm i have selected premieum basic standart .. nothing works

It gives me it does not meet requirements and i have created the template from production environment.

Would love the help.

The error says : the basic edition  does not support the service objective

[image]

When I change it to premium than it still does not work.

**Standard** gives this error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have read threads on MSDN forums before where it has been mentioned that some type of Azure subscriptions like the MSDN Dev/Test subscription or Evaluation subscription have some features not available depending on the region. Please read below thread for more information:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6396ec53-5b34-4dc8-81f8-57e16e207ec6/enterprise-msdn-devtest-sql-database-pricing-tier-not-available?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: trying this on Bizspark maybe that is the problem??

Comment: Try on a different region like Eastern US. You can also try with a regular subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the response that could be the issue. I should create the replica in a different region. Let me check that.

Comment: one of them is UK West one is in UK East. I am able create the databases but do not understand what fails?

Comment: Are you able to change tier of the database using Azure portal GUI?